# Custom fieldable content entity not including GUI-added fields on form

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-entities

I'm building a custom content entity in Drupal 8 and so far done ok. I've used Drupal Console to generate a module and a bundle-less entity for me and added custom fields to this entity using the GUI. I can load the form to add entities of this type with the additional base fields I added in the ContentEntityType annotation.

My issue is that I cannot see the fields I have added through the GUI. If I XDebug my form, the fields are not added to the `$form` array when `parent::buildForm()` or `parent::form()` are called.

I've looked at the Node module for help and in the NodeForm.php's form method, I can step through and see where the GUI-added fields are added when the `form` method in the `ContentEntityForm` class is called.

Having stepped through my entity's form building, I can see it also calls the `form` method in the `ContentEntityForm` class but my GUI fields are not added.

Is there something I'm missing in my custom entity to get the ContentEntityForm to add these?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, I'd completely forgotten about the 'Manage Form Display' page! I just had to move them out of disabled.